# Scheme - List of Fibonacci numbers up to certain value

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, fibonacci

I am trying to write a function that creates a list of the fibonacci sequence but stops when a certain value is found in the list, then returns that list (I hope that makes sense).

So for example if I give it fib-list(55), the function should return:
`(1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55)`

So it's not the 55th fibonacci number I want, its the list UP TO the value 55.

The code I have for returning the list so far looks like this:

```
; Create a list of the fibonacci sequence up to n.
(define (fib-list n)
  ; n = n, f2 = 1, f1 = 1, fs = a list.
  (let loop ((n n) (f2 1) (f1 1) (fs (list)))
    (cond
      ; If n = 0, return reversed list.
      ((zero? n) (reverse fs))
      ; Check if n is in list. If so, return list.
      ((equal? n (car fs)) fs)
      ;Else, find the next fibonacci number and add it to the list.
      (else (loop (- n 1) f1 (+ f2 f1) (cons f2 fs))))))

(display (fib-list 55))
```

My main problem is finding if an element is in the list, because at the moment I just get an error on the line where I am trying to write the `((equal?` statement.

The error says:

```
mcar: contract violation
  expected: mpair?
  given: '()
```

I am still very VERY new to Scheme, so my understanding of the language as a whole isn't great. So please be gentle when telling me why my code sucks/doesn't make sense.

Comment: You're current code is a weird hybrid between two ways of thinking about this: (1) take a fib-number `n` and return a list of the fib-numbers up to it. (2) take an index-number `n` and return a list of the fib-numbers up to that _index_, or iow, up to `F(n)`. Your `(zero? n)` base case and `(- n 1)` recursion suggests (2), but your `(equal? n (car fs))` base case and your `(fib-list 55)` example suggest (1). Which one do you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(list)` creates an empty list, and on the first iteration you get to `(car fs)`, which tries to apply `car` to an empty list, and that's an error.

Your code seems a bit confused about the nature of `n`.
Your description says that it's the largest number you want, but you're recursing like you want the `n:th` Fibonacci number - terminating on `(zero? n)` and recursing on `(- n 1)`.

When you're recursing you're still looking for numbers up to the same limit.
Thus, you should not decrement your limit and terminate on zero, you should leave the limit alone and terminate when you reach larger numbers.

Here's how I would write it:

- The initial list is `(1 1)`
- At each step:

  - Compute the next fibonacci number
  - If this is greater than the limit, reverse the accumulator list and return it
  - Otherwise, `cons` it to the accumulator and recurse with the "new" last two fibonacci number.

In code:

```
(define (fib-list n)
  (let loop ((f2 1) (f1 1) (fs '(1 1)))
    (let ((next (+ f1 f2)))
      (if (> next n) 
          (reverse fs)
          (loop f1 next (cons next fs))))))
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much.

Comment: This code looks good and the OP's error is corrected, but gives an incorrect result for values of `n` less than 1.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way you can do it using continuation-passing style. By adding a continuation parameter to our loop, we effectively create our own *return* mechanism. One unique property of this implementation is the output list is built in forward order and does not need to be reversed when `n` reaches zero.

```
(define (fib-list n)
  (let loop ((n n) (a 0) (b 1) (return identity))
    (if (zero? n)
        (return empty)
        (loop (sub1 n)
              b
              (+ a b)
              (lambda (rest) (return (cons a rest)))))))

(fib-list 10)
;; '(0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34)
```

Reading your question a little closer, in `fib-list(N)` you need `N` to be the stopping condition for your loop, not the *Nth* term in the list. This is actually easier to implement as there's no need to count the number of terms generated.

```
(define (fib-list max)
  (let loop ((a 0) (b 1) (return identity))
    (if (> a max)
        (return empty)
        (loop b
              (+ a b)
              (lambda (rest) (return (cons a rest)))))))

(fib-list 55)
;; '(0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55)

(fib-list 1000)
;; '(0 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377 610 987)
```

Answer (score 1):

#### What's going wrong with the `car` function?

The `car` function takes the first element of a list, but if the list is empty it doesn't have a first element. The `fs` list starts out as empty. When you try to take the first element of an empty list you get this error message:

```
> (car (list))
mcar: contract violation
  expected: mpair?
  given: ()
```

If the list isn't empty, then it has a first element, and it's fine:

```
> (car (list 4 5 6))
4
```

#### Following what you meant in the comment

However, your comment "Check if n is in list" leads me to believe that `(equal?  n (car fs))` is not what you want anyway. The function for determining whether an element is in a list is called [`member`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/r6rs/r6rs-lib-std/r6rs-lib-Z-H-4.html#node_idx_226).

```
#!r6rs
(import (rnrs base)
        (rnrs lists))

> (if (member 4 (list 1 2 4 8))
      "it's in the list"
      "go fish")
"it's in the list"
> (if (member 5 (list 1 2 4 8))
      "it's in the list"
      "go fish")
"go fish"
```

So with that `(equal? n (car fs))` test replaced with `(member n fs)`, your code looks like:

```
; Create a list of the fibonacci sequence up to n.
(define (fib-list n)
  ; n = n, f2 = 1, f1 = 1, fs = a list.
  (let loop ((n n) (f2 1) (f1 1) (fs (list)))
    (cond
      ; If n = 0, return reversed list.
      ((zero? n) (reverse fs))
      ; Check if n is in list. If so, return list.
      ((member n fs) fs)
      ;Else, find the next fibonacci number and add it to the list.
      (else (loop (- n 1) f1 (+ f2 f1) (cons f2 fs))))))

> (fib-list 55)
(10946 6765 4181 2584 1597 987 610 377 233 144 89 55 34 21 13 8 5 3 2 1 1)
```

This is not the answer you wanted though; you wanted `(1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55)`.

#### Why is the list going past `55`?

One of the problems is that the `n` is shadowed, in the same way that in this expression:

```
> (let ([n 5])
    (let ([n 10])
      n))
10
```

The `n` in the body refers to `10` instead of `5`.

The result is going past `55` because inside the loop `n` is shadowed and has become a different number. I'm guessing in your comment about "check if n is in list", you meant "check if the original n is in list". To do that you have to rename one of the `n`s:

```
> (let ([orig-n 5])
    (let ([n 10])
      orig-n))
5
```

In the context of your code:

```
; Create a list of the fibonacci sequence up to n.
(define (fib-list orig-n)
  ; n = n, f2 = 1, f1 = 1, fs = a list.
  (let loop ((n orig-n) (f2 1) (f1 1) (fs (list)))
    (cond
      ; If n = 0, return reversed list.
      ((zero? n) (reverse fs))
      ; Check if orig-n is in list. If so, return list.
      ((member orig-n fs) fs)
      ;Else, find the next fibonacci number and add it to the list.
      (else (loop (- n 1) f1 (+ f2 f1) (cons f2 fs))))))

> (fib-list 55)
(55 34 21 13 8 5 3 2 1 1)
```

#### Reversing

This is closer, but it's reversed. You have *two* base cases, the `(zero? n)` case and the `(member orig-n fs)` case. In one of those it's reversed and in one of them it's not. Changing them both to call reverse fixes it:

```
; Create a list of the fibonacci sequence up to n.
(define (fib-list orig-n)
  ; n = n, f2 = 1, f1 = 1, fs = a list.
  (let loop ((n orig-n) (f2 1) (f1 1) (fs (list)))
    (cond
      ; If n = 0, return reversed list.
      ((zero? n) (reverse fs))
      ; Check if orig-n is in list. If so, return reversed list.
      ((member orig-n fs) (reverse fs))
      ;Else, find the next fibonacci number and add it to the list.
      (else (loop (- n 1) f1 (+ f2 f1) (cons f2 fs))))))

> (fib-list 55)
(1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55)
```

#### Small numbers

This is correct on large Fibonacci numbers like `55`, but it still does something weird on small numbers:

```
> (fib-list 2)
(1 1)
> (fib-list 3)
(1 1 2)
```

If you only want it to stop when it gets to `orig-n`, then maybe the decreasing `n` argument is not needed, and is actually making it stop too early. Removing it (and removing the zero check for it) makes the `member` check the only stopping case.

This is *dangerous*, because it could go into an infinite loop if you give it a non-Fibonacci number as input. However, it fixes the small-number examples:

```
; Create a list of the fibonacci sequence up to n.
; The `orig-n` MUST be a fibonacci number to begin with,
; otherwise this loops forever.
(define (fib-list orig-n)
  ; f2 = 1, f1 = 1, fs = a list.
  (let loop ((f2 1) (f1 1) (fs (list)))
    (cond
      ; Check if orig-n is in list. If so, return reversed list.
      ((member orig-n fs) (reverse fs))
      ;Else, find the next fibonacci number and add it to the list.
      (else (loop f1 (+ f2 f1) (cons f2 fs))))))

> (fib-list 55)
(1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55)
> (fib-list 2)
(1 1 2)
> (fib-list 3)
(1 1 2 3)
```

And finally, consider what happens vs. what should happen if you give it a number like `56`.

```
> (fib-list 56)
;infinite loop
```

This is a design decision that you have not specified in your question (yet), but there are ways of solving it either way.

### Update: `orig-n` or greater

> I should have specified that I need to check if there is a number that is greater than OR equal to `orig-n`. Can I still use the `member` function to check for this or will I need to use something different?

You will have to use something different. Just above `member` in the documentation is the [`memp`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/r6rs/r6rs-lib-std/r6rs-lib-Z-H-4.html#node_idx_224) function (you could also use [`exists`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/r6rs/r6rs-lib-std/r6rs-lib-Z-H-4.html#node_idx_206) in this case). The `mem` is short for member, and the `p` is short for "predicate". It determines whether any member of the list matches a certain predicate.

```
> (if (memp positive? (list -4 -2 -3 5 -1))
      "one of them is positive"
      "go fish")
"one of them is positive"
> (if (memp positive? (list -4 -2 -3 -5 -1))
      "one of them is positive"
      "go fish")
"go fish"
> (define (five-or-greater? n)
    (>= n 5))
> (if (memp five-or-greater? (list -4 -2 -3 6 -1))
      "one of them is equal to 5 or greater"
      "go fish")
"one of them is equal to 5 or greater"
> (if (memp five-or-greater? (list -4 -2 -3 4 -1))
      "one of them is equal to 5 or greater"
      "go fish")
"go fish"
```

To use it for "orig-n or greater", you would have to define a function like:

```
(define (orig-n-or-greater? n)
  (>= n orig-n))
```

As a *local* function inside your main function, so that it can refer to `orig-n`. Then you can use it like `(memp orig-n-or-greater? fs)`.

```
; Create a list of the fibonacci sequence up to n.
(define (fib-list orig-n)
  (define (orig-n-or-greater? n)
    (>= n orig-n))
  ; f2 = 1, f1 = 1, fs = a list.
  (let loop ((f2 1) (f1 1) (fs (list)))
    (cond
      ; Check if orig-n or greater is in list. If so, return reversed list.
      ((memp orig-n-or-greater? fs) (reverse fs))
      ;Else, find the next fibonacci number and add it to the list.
      (else (loop f1 (+ f2 f1) (cons f2 fs))))))

> (fib-list 3)
(1 1 2 3)
> (fib-list 55)
(1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55)
> (fib-list 56)
(1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I realise now that I should have specified that I need to check if there is a number that is greater than OR equal to orig-n. Can I still use the member function to check for this or will I need to use something different?

Comment: I have updated my answer to check if there's a number that is greater than or equal to `orig-n`. It uses the `memp` function instead of `member`.